# ClassPathResource does not get the classpath

Tags: java, spring, classpath

In my application, I would like to use a resource that exist in a folder `media/src/main/resources/testMediaExif`

To get that path, I used this piece of code, located in `media/src/main/java/com/project/MyClass.java`:

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("classpath:testMediaExif");
File file = resource.getFile();
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

The error shown is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath:testMediaExif] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

If I change that code:

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("testMediaExif");
```

The variable absolutePath takes this value:

```
/Users/blanca/desarrollo/media/target/test-classes/testMediaExif
```

Why does it point to the target path? How could I change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that the absolute path issue is because of the outputDirectory in the  target of your maven POM . In my project the outputDirectory war/WEB-INF/classes and the it is from here the classes get executed . If I change it to some junk value , the class no longer gets executed .

So I believe the absolute path has to do something with the location of your .class files . Hope this helps .

Comment: You are totally right!
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java"/>

Comment: Thhese .classpath file is automatically generated, and I am afraid of the consequencies that this change could have in other tests. At least I know the reason of my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

There are two problems with `new ClassPathResource("classpath:testMediaExif")`:

1. The `classpath:` prefix is only used in config files (e.g. XML files), and should not be used if you're using `ClasspathResource` directly.
2. `classpath:testMediaExif` refers to a resource in the root of the classpath, not relative to the file in which you're making the reference.

Try this instead:

```
new ClasspathResource("testMediaExif", getClass())
```

or

```
new ClasspathResource("testMediaExif", MyClass.class)
```

These will construct a refernce to a resource called `testMediaExif` relative to `MyClass`.

**One more thing:** `ClasspathResource.getFile()` will only work in the resource really is a file. If it's packed in a JAR, then it won't work.

Comment: Thanks, with your approach, the problem comes when I try to get the absolute path. new ClasspathResource("testMediaExif", getClass())
 gets the path where the class is, but getAbsolutePath points to target folder again