# How to use Spring ClassPathResource: with classpath: or classpath*: and leading / or not?

Tags: java, spring

I having file in the location

```
--src
  --> main
   --> config
    --> application
     --> context
      --> reference
       --> user
        --> user.xml
```

where

```
    --src
      --> main
       --> config
```

is in the classpath. Now I am trying to access the file using

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("classpath**:/application/context/references/user/user.xml");
File file = resource.getFile();
```

But I getting `FileNotFoundException`, I tried with

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("classpath:/application/context/references/user/user.xml");
File file = resource.getFile();
```

too, but still I getting the exception. Can someone help me to understand the working of `ClassPathResource` and right solution?

Comment: Try to determine the starting path in ClassPath,  `Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("" or File.seperator); resource.getFile().getAbsolutePath();` So that you can give the appropriate value inside new CPR() based on above result

Comment: remove "classpath:", see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8725288/180100) and http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html#ClassPathResource-java.lang.String-

Comment: @RC., you are right, Yesterday I tried the same, but I think I didn't test it correctly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use as below

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/application/context/references/user/user.xml");
File file = resource.getFile();
```

Comment: The leading slash is unnecessary according to the [class documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html): _A leading slash will be removed, as the ClassLoader resource access methods will not accept it._

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [logging_date.txt] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist` It cannot find the file.