# springframework.core.io.Resource always throw java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring

I am a beginner for Spring, and I am learning Resource.

```
package com.smart.beanfactory;

import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class BeanLifeCycle {
    private static void LifeCycleInBeanFactory() {
        Resource res = new ClassPathResource("classpath:com/smart/beanfactory/beans.xml");
        try {
            System.out.println(res.getURL());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.fillInStackTrace());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LifeCycleInBeanFactory();
    }
}
```

I write the above simple code just to use the classpath to load the .xml file.

Below is the hierarchy of my project:
[image]

Then I tried the absolute file path in `Resource res = new ClassPathResource("file:/Users/haoxu/Documents/Code/Java/anotherchapter4/src/main/resources/com.smart/beanfactory/beans.xml");`
But that also cannot work.
It just told me "java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Users/haoxu/Documents/Code/Java/anotherchapter4/src/main/resources/com.smart/beanfactory/beans.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
"

-----------update--------

I modified my code to:

```
package com.smart.beanfactory;

import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import java.io.File;

public class BeanLifeCycle {
    private static void LifeCycleInBeanFactory() {
        Resource res = new ClassPathResource("/com/smart/beanfactory/beans.xml");
        try {
            System.out.println(res.getURL());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.fillInStackTrace());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LifeCycleInBeanFactory();
    }
}
```

But I still get "java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/smart/beanfactory/beans.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist"

Comment: have you tried `"com.smart.beanfactory/beans.xml"` like it shows in the project tree?

Comment: I tried it but it cannot work.  java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com.smart.beanfactory/beans.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Comment: Maybe it's the directory, instead of the com.smart.beqnfactory you should use a plain folder named xml or something then in the resource creation use "/xml/beans.xml".

Answer (score 2):

The prefix `classpath:` is not required for `ClassPathResource`

Comment: agree. See the explanation on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588915/how-spring-classpathresource-is-working

Comment: according to your screenshot there is no beans.xml file in classpath. See under "target/..." dir. beans.xml file must appear there automatically when you run your app

Comment: Yes. My IDE seems does not put the .xml file to the target/ dir. I do it by myself and then the code works!

Comment: The target directory is the result of the build, you shouldn't be adding files to it.

Answer (score 0):

try the below line with your code

```
Resource res = new ClassPathResource("/resources/com/smart/beanfactory/beans.xml");
```

Comment: still get java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/com/smart/beanfactory/beans.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Comment: It should work have included "/" like "/resources/com/smart/beanfactory/beans.xml" this?

Answer (score 0):

I copy and paste the file "beans.xml" to the directory "target/classes/com/smart/beanfactory/". The hierarchy is like below
[image]

My code is like below:

```
package com.smart.beanfactory;

import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import java.io.File;

public class BeanLifeCycle {
    private static void LifeCycleInBeanFactory() {
        Resource res = new ClassPathResource("com/smart/beanfactory/beans.xml");
        try {
            System.out.println(res.getURL());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.fillInStackTrace());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LifeCycleInBeanFactory();
    }
}
```

The result is "file:/Users/haoxu/Documents/Code/Java/anotherchapter4/target/classes/com/smart/beanfactory/beans.xml
"

This is actually the path of the file. But it is in the target directory. I think that is really **strange**.